# error en la creacion de clave foranea

Tags: sql

Estoy aprendiendo SQL y en un trabajo que debo hacer hoy, me encontre con el error que les presento abajo.
Las tablas las cree con exito, pero a la hora de crear la constraint me resulta ese error...

```
CREATE TABLE TIPO_BENEFICIO (
    id_beneficio              NUMBER(38) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    beneficios                VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
); 

CREATE TABLE SALUD (
    id_salud  NUMBER(38) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    salud     VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE TIPO_BENEFICIO
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SAL_BEN FOREIGN KEY ( SALUD_id_salud )
        REFERENCES SALUD ( id_salud );
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error que empieza en la línea: 139 del comando :
ALTER TABLE TIPO_BENEFICIO
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SAL_BEN FOREIGN KEY ( SALUD_id_salud )
        REFERENCES SALUD ( id_salud )

Informe de error -
ORA-00904: "SALUD_ID_SALUD": identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando intentas crear la clave foránea

```
ALTER TABLE TIPO_BENEFICIO ADD CONSTRAINT FK_SAL_BEN FOREIGN KEY ( SALUD_id_salud ) REFERENCES SALUD ( id_salud );
```

indicás que la columna **SALUD_id_salud** de la tabla **tipo_beneficio** refiere a la columna **id_salud** de la tabla **salud**.

Mientras que en la creación de la tabla **tipo_beneficio**, no estas indicando que contiene la columna **SALUD_id_salud**.

Tu SQL tendría que ser algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE TIPO_BENEFICIO (
    id_beneficio              NUMBER(38) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    beneficios                VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    SALUD_id_salud            NUMBER(38)
);
```

Comment: incluso así, el error sigue

Comment: Borraste la tabla tipo_beneficio anterior?